# NLog - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, connection-string, nlog

I've seen there's numerous threads refering this problem. I've read them and I can't see nothing wrong with code that I've writen.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.mono2.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        internalLogLevel="info"
        internalLogFile="c:\log.txt">
    <targets>
        <target type="Database"
                name="database"
                connectionstring="NLogPriMIODbConnection">
            <commandText>
                exec dbo.usp_InsertLogEntry @logLevel, @createDate, null,
                                     @message, null, @exception, @stackTrace, @origin
            </commandText>
            <parameter name="@createDate"
                        layout="${longdate}" />
            <parameter name="@origin"
                        layout="${callsite}" />
            <parameter name="@logLevel"
                        layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="@message"
                        layout="${message}" />
            <parameter name="@exception"
                        layout="${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}" />
            <parameter name="@stackTrace"
                        layout="${stacktrace}" />
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*"
                minlevel="Trace"
                writeTo="database" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Connection string is following http://www.connectionstrings.com/ standards for SQL 2012

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add 
       name="NLogPriMIODbConnection" 
       connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=local.XXX;User Id=sa;Password=XXX;" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What seems to be this mysterious problem that I can't find?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your NLog config you used `connectionstring` which expects the actual string (ie. the server, the username, password, etc.).  If you want it to use a named connection string from your web/app config, you need to use `connectionstringname` instead.

Comment: How could i have not noticed that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is how mine would would look using your values, having the connection string as a nested node for the target. Im sure there are other ways of doing it but that is how my current config is and it works.

Or if you are looking to pull the connection string from the app.config (as said in other answers) you would want to use the ConnectionStringName prop

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.mono2.xsd"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     internalLogLevel="info" internalLogFile="c:\log.txt">
  <targets>
    <target type="Database" name="database">
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="NLogPriMIODbConnection" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=local.XXX;User Id=sa;Password=XXX;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <commandText>
        exec dbo.usp_InsertLogEntry @logLevel, @createDate, null, @message, null, @exception, @stackTrace, @origin
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@createDate" layout="${longdate}" />
      <parameter name="@origin" layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@logLevel" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}" />
      <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${stacktrace}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace"  writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```